# Why is there a 100 times difference in the execution time of the same JS code between Google Chrome and Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, performance, browser, javascript, chromium

Recently, I found a website that uses a third-party chromium browser badly, but it is normal in Google Chrome; After comparative analysis, it is found that the reason is probably that there is a long JS execution time. I extracted the JS code and put it on a simple test page.
The comparative test shows that it takes 30ms to use chrome, but it takes more than 3 seconds to use chromium. I can't find the reason. What factors lead to the difference? I tested various versions of chromium (M86, M88, M90, m92).
The following is my test page, the key code:

```
for (var td_GE = 0; td_GE < event.renderedBuffer.length; td_GE++) {
    td_Md.update(event.renderedBuffer.getChannelData(0)[td_GE].toString());
}
```

The complete test page can be accessed:
https://linxin2020.github.io/hls_live/js_performance.html
[image: chrome test]

[image: chrome test]

Comment: Chrome might be "based" on Chromium, but it will have a lot of per-platform optimisations, both in the javascript engine and in the display rendering system. The should not be considered the "same" by any stretch and they have different goals.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium does not have an official stable release. It is a continuous beta program and so is expected to be buggy. You might have downloaded an unpolished build of Chromium releases.

The MXX releases are milestone releases of Chrome which are forked from Chromium every four weeks. The stability of the Chromium browsers used in your tests depend on where you downloaded it from. It is most likely that they are unpolished builds.

---

**Edit:**

Here are some of the tests performed in on the Chromium source code before publishing. I'll first link this [old answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/1025) which gives an overview of the tests performed. Note that the WebKit Tests include JavascriptCore tests which measures things like JS execution performance. This answer is outdated because as of 2013 Google forked WebKit engine to Blink for future builds.

Here are the documentations I could find on the current phase of tests:

- [Legacy Docs](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/testing)
- [New Docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/testing/testing_in_chromium.md)

Some pages in the legacy docs are now moved to the new site, Performance Tests for example is now moved to Telemetry in the new docs.

You can see that the tests are categorized into:

- Unit Tests (for additional features)
- Browser Tests (UX tests)
- Web Tests (Blink Engine tests)
- Telemetry (Feature performance and benchmarking tests)
- Instrumentation Tests (for Android)
- EarlGrey (for iOS)
- Fuzzer Tests (Security and Stability)
- Tast (for ChromeOS)

The [Web Tests](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/testing/web_tests.md) cover JS executions.

Maybe Chromium builds don't run these unit tests, or maybe Google has their own set of proprietary tests which are more optimized, which is very likely since they are Google.

Comment: I tested many chromium versions from different channels in windows, and the results were similar, which shows that this is a common problem.

Comment: But Chromium does not have a stable release channel. The builds you downloaded are probably from a third-party developer. Officially Google applies patches to Chromium and releases it to the Chrome Canary channel. From there it moves all the way to Chrome Stable after further testing. These tests and optimizations are Google's proprietary code and are probably not applied by third-party builds. One of those tests could include checks for JS code execution speed. Chromium is a rough testbed from where polished releases are made.

Comment: I've updated my answer with details of tests performed while releasing stable builds.